# Web Method is not calling

Tags: c#, webmethod

I am using Web Method in C# and through Ajax calling that web method. But the web method not called.

I need to load chart dynamically using asp.net with c# method. So I have used web method to interact with client side. Please look the following below code. My web method is not calling

```
Aspx Page:

<script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function ShowCurrentTime() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CS.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
        data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
}
</script> 
</head>
<body style = "font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
Your Name : 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time" 
    onclick = "ShowCurrentTime()" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: " 
        + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
}
```

Getting "Undefined". Requires your help

Comment: have you tried debugging the code? does it reach your method??

Comment: What is the full URL of your API?

Comment: Not reaching the method. Full URL  D:\Dash_05\test\test . mine C# code and Aspx code is there. Please post by rewriting the code

Answer (score 1):

You are calling it as POST from the web page, but on the controller it is a GET (which is the default)

Add `[HttpPost]` attribute to fix or change the ajax call to GET (probably better).

Comment: Please could you give the syntax for this

Comment: change `type: "POST"` to `type: "GET"`

Comment: The steps i followed is :

Comment: Aspx page after to <form tag><asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" /></form>

Comment: In App_Start folder, RouteConfig file

Comment: comment //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
Add this line--->            settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;

Answer (score 0):

there is problem with the jquery syntax. and correct syntax should be as below.
Please try the below corrected code and let me know.

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function ShowCurrentTime() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CS.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
        data: {name: $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>").val()},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Its not working. After entering values in the text box and clicking button, its showing "undefined"

Comment: i have changed the code please check now. changed response.d to response in on success as well as in failure method

Answer (score -1):

Can you add this lines to web.config code below these are for reach get and post protocols:

```
 <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
```